# How to get my service to start an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

I have my service working, but for some reason it will not start my activity. It does not show an error in the logcat either. I want my service to start another activity. Is that possible? I checked to make sure my if statement was correct and it is. It does print out the HELLO.

service code below:

```
package com.example.textsmslock;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class Logs extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
     @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            System.out.println("LOGS STARTED");
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            Iterator i = l.iterator();
            PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
            while(i.hasNext()) 
            {
                ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
                try 
                {
                    CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                    Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
                    //System.out.println("this is the charsequence: " + c);
                    //System.out.println("this is the log: " + Log.w("LABEL", c.toString()));
                    if(c.equals("Messaging"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("HELLO \n");

                        startActivity(new intent(("com.example.textsmslock.Enable"));

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) 
                {
                    //Name Not FOund Exception
                }
        }
       @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            System.out.println("LOGS STOPPED"); 
       }
}
```

android manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Enable"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_enable" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.textsmslock.Enable" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<service android:name=".Logs" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to the activity intent.

This line

```
startActivity(new intent(("com.example.textsmslock.Enable"));
```

Should now be

```
Intent i = new Intent( this, YourActivity.class );
i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
startActivity( i );
```